# Why people follow different approach to define function in javascript

Tags: javascript

few years back people always define function like this way

```
1) function foo() {}
```

now i have noticed people define function like this way

```
2) var foo= function () {}

3) foo: function() {}

4) var GaugeBar = GaugeBar || {};
   GaugeBar.generate = function (percentage) {}
```

so anyone JavaScript expert would tell me why people follow different approach for defining function? each signature has any special significance ?

when we should follow which one?

looking for good explanation. thanks

Comment: Options 3 and 4 aren't just defining functions.

Comment: so tell me what is option 3 and 4.

Comment: They are defining methods on an object (option 3 is not a complete JavaScript statement on its own). If you didn't know that, I suggest going through some tutorials on JavaScript, particularly about how to create and use objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some confusion in your question - the only valid approach to define a function is 1) and 2). The other two are just different uses of functions in objects.

I personally like to define **named functions** (`function myFunc () {}`) because if my program crashes the function names will appear in stack traces. However, there are situations where I use anonymous functions if those functions are not part of a public API or if they are used only once in my program.

Option 3) is basically a function that gets assigned to an object:

```
var myObject =
{ func: function () {}
, func2: function () {}
}
```

Option 4) is merely a way how to ensure that a variable contains an object and after that adding some functions to that object.

In practical terms, there is no difference whether you give your functions a name or you use anonymous functions (except for the stack traces and for differences already described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?lq=1)) and I believe it depends on the programmer's preferred code style. I would love if everyone named their publicly accessible functions as it makes debugging easier, but that's up to each developer to decide.

Comment: Aren't there some differences between function expressions and declarations?

Comment: There definitely are - I updated the answer with a link to another SO question that details these differences in greater detail.